# How to resize a button in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms. I tried this code but it has not worked; how can I resize the buttons?

```
<ContentView.Content>
  <StackLayout>
    <Button Text="1" WidthRequest="50"></Button>
    <Button Text="2" WidthRequest="50"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<StackLayout >
    <Button Text="1" WidthRequest="50" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
    <Button Text="2" WidthRequest="50" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: In my case I had `HorizontalOptions="Fill"` and to set the WidthRequest property in my code behind file had no effects. I set it to Center (or Start or End) and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can use HorizontalOptions attribute to make the width or height be as large as needed to contain the elements within it.

```
<Button  HorizontalOptions="Center"  Text="Retry" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  <StackLayout>
    <!--I am wider but shorter-->
    <Button Text="1" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="50"></Button>
    <!--I am narrower but longer-->
    <Button Text="2" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="100"></Button>
    <!--I fill the whole width. See also VerticalOptions-->
    <Button Text="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Size parent View, for example if it's in a StackLayout, it'll be same size with parent.

```
   <Grid HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="120" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button Text="Hello!" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
        </Grid>
```

It'll be shown 120 x 120,

Because, Button's Default HorizontalOptions is Fill, VerticalOptions is Start. But some Controls like buttons, ignores Height or Width request and prefer to fill parent. Other elements in the same Layout effects button. Just resize parent of button and leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below mentioned method:

```
<StackPanel> 
   <Button Content = "Button1" Height = "30" Width = "80" Foreground = "Blue" FontSize = "12" Margin = "10"/>
   <Button Content = "Button2" Height = "30" Width = "80" Foreground = "Blue" FontSize = "12" Margin = "10"/>
   <Button Content = "Button3" Height = "30" Width = "80" Foreground = "Blue" FontSize = "12" Margin = "10"/> 
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Test your code. In Xamarin Forms, you need to set `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest`. Attempting to set `Height` and `Width` won't compile: those are read-only properties.