# How to set a XAML Button size inside a CollectionView.Footer?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, frontend, collectionview

[image]

I have a button within my CollectionView Footer that reaches the ends of the screen horizontally. I want to be able to set the width either to the size of the text, or to a width I pick.

Changing HorizontalOptions does nothing. I've been messing around with :

- WidthRequest
- MinimumWidthRequest
- HeightRequest
- MinimumHeightRequest

These options only affect button height.

Comment: **Show the code** that you wrote, which results in that symptom.

Comment: use `WidthRequest`.  But without knowing anything about your layout it's impossible to say why that's not working.  As @ToolmakerSteve suggests, you need to post the relevant code.  Please read [ask] for more guidance on writing a good question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize a button in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39769793/how-to-resize-a-button-in-xamarin). Found this and similar answers by google `xamarin forms button widthrequest has no effect`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can set a grid in footer, then set the width and height of grid ,code like:

```
<CollectionView.Footer>
//width&height
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,100,*"
RowDefinitions="50">
<Button Grid.Column="1",Text="Click" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
</Grid>
</CollectionView.Footer>
```